# Importing variables in create-react-app SassError: Undefined variable

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app with SCSS style-files. There are `App.scss`, where I include all of `.scss` stylesheets and `variables.scss` where i decline all project variables.

When I import `variables.scss` into `App.scss` and then import all components style-files I get an error `SassError: Undefined variable: $grey` which I use in `border-bottom: 1px solid $grey` in `Header.scss` file.

If I import `variables.scss` into the `Header.scss` the error is gone and all of things work correctly. But I don't want to include variables into every component `.scss` file.

**What should I do to use variables from `variables.scss` in all my project files?**

What I've tried:

- rename `variables.scss` to `_variables.scss` and import as `@import 'components/variables';`
- import `variables.scss` before other imports in `App.scss`
- import `variables.scss` into `index.scss` directly
- searching here for the answer (nothing helped)

**variables.scss**

```
$grey: #fefefe;
$black: #000000;
```

**App.scss**

```
@import 'components/variables';
@import 'components/header/Header.scss';
```

**project structure**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT9m6.png)

Comment: node-sass in your project is already install or not ?

Comment: @KolaCaine yes, I've installed node-sass already

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I found the problem solving.

I import SASS-files not ony into `App.scss`, but also in relative component `.js`-files.
So, the problem gone when I remove `import './Header.scss'` from `Header.js` file.